# Separating variables values in the url

Tags: php

How I can seperate the variable values in the url?

Let's take the following url for exmaple:

```
www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2
```

And instead of that: a=1 b=2

I'm getinng a=1&b=2 and b=2.

Is there any character that seperates the values?or an alternative solution?

Comment: Show us the code you are using. This is really easy to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `$_GET` superglobal to get these values:

```
echo $_GET['a']; // outputs 1
echo $_GET['b']; // outputs 2
```

Comment: I'll mark you answer as a solution as soon as possible, thanks.